# Wait for URL change in Casper.js?

Tags: javascript, casperjs

There is a `waitForUrl()` functionality in `Casper.js`, but is it possible to `waitForUrlChange()` in `Casper.js`?

I mean detecting a change in `this.getCurrentUrl()` value. I can't predict the new url value. It can be anything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not built in, but you can write your own pretty easy:

```
casper.waitForUrlChange = function(then, onTimeout, timeout){
    var oldUrl;
    this.then(function(){
        oldUrl = this.getCurrentUrl();
    }).waitFor(function check(){
        return oldUrl === this.getCurrentUrl();
    }, then, onTimeout, timeout);
    return this;
};
```

This is a proper function extension, because it has the same semantics as the other `wait*` functions (arguments are optional and it waits) and it supports the builder pattern (also called promise pattern by some).

As [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28074458/wait-for-url-change-in-casper-js/28074554?noredirect=1#comment44703130_28074554) by Darren Cook, one could improve this further by checking whether `waitForUrlChange` already exists in CasperJS and using a dynamic arguments list for when CasperJS changes its API:

```
if (!casper.waitForUrlChange) {
    casper.waitForUrlChange = function(){
        var oldUrl;
        // add the check function to the beginning of the arguments...
        Array.prototype.unshift.call(arguments, function check(){
            return oldUrl === this.getCurrentUrl();
        });
        this.then(function(){
            oldUrl = this.getCurrentUrl();
        });
        this.waitFor.apply(this, arguments);
        return this;
    };
}
```

Comment: Great approach. I wondered if there was a way to use `Arguments` to forward all params to `waitFor()`. Then if a 4th param is ever added to `waitFor()` this function will be future-proof. Also maybe prefix it with `if(!casper.waitForUrlChange)` in case the function ever gets added to core CasperJS?

Comment: @DarrenCook Thanks! And I learned something doing it. I didn't know one could simply piggy-back the function in the `arguments` object because it is not an array.

Comment: Future-proof now, but requiring more brain energy (or copious comments) to work out what it is doing :-)

Answer (score 8):

There's an event handler for it

```
casper.on('url.changed',function(url) {
casper.echo(url);
});
```

Here's the documentation for it: http://casperjs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#url-changed

However, as Artjom B. mentioned, this won't cover all cases that a function extension would handle. It's only really appropriate when you don't need it as part of the control flow, but just want to reactively scrape some values when it happens.

Comment: The problem with this is that you break out of the control flow. You still need at least a `waitFor` to wait for the event to occurr.

Comment: That's a fair criticism. I'll update the answer to highlight the issue.