# CasperJS - Access page's content while trying to fill drop-down menu through a loop

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, casperjs

I'm trying some tests with casperjs and the certain situation here is:

> - extracting city names from a drop-down menu, (Already Done)
> - then select each city (with `casper.fill()`) which leads to load new
>     contents and URL change on the page, (**Successful** while testing with a single city name, **Failed** with loop through the list of cities' names)
> - go one level further through *new loaded items'* links (new pages),
> - finally, grab the content from each single page

I was trying to do a loop to iterate through cities list and do all the work in each cycle. But the problem is `CasperJs` attempts to set `<option>` field value to each city one after another immediately and without executing the rest of the code inside the loop:

```
casper.then(function() {

    var citiesLength = cities.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < citiesLength; i++) {

        this.fill('form.wpv-filter-form',{   //setting drop-down field value to the city names in order of the items in the array
            'city[]': cityNames[i]
        });

// Apparently the code below (to the end of the loop) doesn't get executed
        casper.thenEvaluate(function() {

// Here the url change is being checked to know when the new content is loaded:
            var regexString = '(\\?)(city)(\\[\\])(=)(' + cityNames[i] + ')&';
            var regex = new RegExp(regexString, "igm");

            this.waitForUrl(regex, function(){
                var name = this.getHTML('.kw-details-title');
                link = this.evaluate(getFirstItemLink); // for test, just getting the first item's link

                casper.open(link).then(function(){
                    this.echo("New Page is loaded......");
                    // Grab the single item contents
                });
            });

        });
    }
```

This is the log (Shortened for 3 cities):

```
[debug] [remote] Set "city[]" field value to city1
[info] [remote] attempting to fetch form element from selector: 'form.wpv-filter-form'
[debug] [remote] Set "city[]" field value to city2
[info] [remote] attempting to fetch form element from selector: 'form.wpv-filter-form'
[debug] [remote] Set "city[]" field value to city3
[info] [remote] attempting to fetch form element from selector: 'form.wpv-filter-form'
[info] [remote] attempting to fetch form element from selector: 'form.wpv-filter-form'
[info] [remote] attempting to fetch form element from selector: 'form.wpv-filter-form'
[info] [phantom] Step anonymous 5/5: done in 123069ms.
[info] [phantom] Step _step 6/79 https ://domain.com/section/ (HTTP 200)
[info] [phantom] Step _step 6/79: done in 123078ms.
```

P.s: Is the usage of `casper.open()` a good way to reach second level pages (item pages)? Do I need to close them somehow after taking their content?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have many issues in your code. Like not matching steps (`then*` and `wait*` functions) together which means that you mix direct invocation (`casper.fill`) with a step (`thenEvaluate`).

The other issue is that `this` doesn't refer to `casper` inside of the page context (inside `evaluate` and `thenEvaluate`).

This should work:

```
cityNames.forEach(function(cityName){
    casper.then(function(){
        this.fill('form.wpv-filter-form', {   //setting drop-down field value to the city names in order of the items in the array
            'city[]': cityName
        });
    });

    casper.then(function(){
        var regexString = '(\\?)(city)(\\[\\])(=)(' + cityName + ')&';
        var regex = new RegExp(regexString, "igm");
        this.waitForUrl(regex, function(){
            var name = this.getHTML('.kw-details-title');
            link = this.evaluate(getFirstItemLink); // for test, just getting the first item's link

            this.thenOpen(link).then(function(){
                this.echo("New Page is loaded......");
                // Grab the single item contents
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks dear Artjom, I had to wrap your code inside a `casper.then()` to be executed. Also, apparently I should add `cityName` argument to the method's function which includes `casper.fills()`. Otherwise, it returns an Object to fill the form. I couldn't use `casper. WaitForUrl ()` to continue the loop after the url change and had problems with *invalid url* errors so I disabled regex method and used [your solution here instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28074554/190929). So here's the working code: https://paste.ubuntu.com/24671718/

Comment: __But I still got a big problem, PhantomJS crashes after opening the first link in the first loop.__ I need to open links, grab their content and close them (for the sake of performance). I saw your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32478245/190929  but couldn't fit that to my problem.

Comment: Would you edit your answer as I showed here: ( https://paste.ubuntu.com/24671718/ ) so I mark that as accepted answer? Also if you agree, I post the crashing issue and the question about optimized method to open and close pages; and give the link here.

Comment: Sorry, I had an error in my first version of my answer. Whether you use `waitForUrl` or `waitForUrlChange` doesn't really make a difference. I won't change my answer further, but you can post your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to give you a precise answer because your problem is impossible to reproduce. However, I noted several problems in your script...

### 1. Avoid "nesting hell"

**CasperJS** is organized around *steps*. With this library, a script generally looks like this:

```
casper.start('http://www.website.com/');

casper.then(function () {
  // Step 1
});

casper.then(function () {
  // Step 2
});

casper.then(function () {
  // Step 3
});

casper.run();
```

`then` methods are not promises, but they have the same objective: flattening the code. So when you reach a certain level of nesting, you are obviously doing something wrong.

### 2. Be careful with `evaluate`

From the [documentation](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#evaluate):

> The concept behind this method is probably the most difficult to understand when discovering CasperJS. As a reminder, think of the evaluate() method as a gate between the CasperJS environment and the one of the page you have opened; everytime you pass a closure to evaluate(), you’re entering the page and execute code as if you were using the browser console.

In your case, you are using `this.evaluate()` inside `thenEvaluate()`. I am sure this is not what you want to do...

### 3. `this` is not always what you expect

If we consider our first two points (nesting and `evaluate`), it appears that you are not using `this` the right way. When you are in the PhantomJS/CasperJS environment, `this` is your `casper` instance. But inside `evaluate`, you are in the page DOM environment, which means that `this` becomes `window`. If it's still not clear, here is an example script:

```
var casper = require('casper').create();

casper.start('http://casperjs.org/');

casper.then(function () {
  // "this" is "casper"
  console.log(this.getCurrentUrl()); // http://casperjs.org/
});

casper.then(function () {
  // "this" is "casper"
  this.echo(this.evaluate(function () {
    // "this" is "window"
    return this.location.href; // http://casperjs.org/
  }));
});

casper.run();
```

Comment: Thanks dear Badacadabra; The clarification of `this` in different concepts was very useful. I've reconstructed my code based on your suggestions, but still had no chance. [Here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/24659583/)  is the reconstructed code. The exact problem is exposed as comments inside the code: 
https://paste.ubuntu.com/24659583/